# Already have vim installed, how to re-install over existing?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, vim

I'm on a mac osx and I need to re-install or build VIM with some custom switches.

How should I go about doing this?  Will it just write over the existing or should I un-install somehow?

I know macvim has it (+Ruby interpreter), but I want the standard vim to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the normal make process:

```
./configure; make; make install
```

it will install the new binary `vim` in your `/usr/local/bin` directory.  You can then either run it directly with `/usr/local/bin/vim` or make an alias in your `.bashrc` such as:

```
alias vim="/usr/local/bin/vim"
```

Then when you type `vim` at the command prompt it will run the new version of vim.  The old version will remain at `/usr/bin/vim`.  I wouldn't recommend deleting it as you may need to run it in the future.

Comment: You can also change your PATH so /usr/local/bin is searched before /usr/bin.  BTW, another reason to put your custom vim in /usr/local/bin and leave the regular one alone, is so your custom version won't get randomly overwritten by a system update.

Answer (score 1):

I know that building something from source can be a weird source of pleasure — that's what I feel anyway — but there is a regular (CLI) Vim executable within MacVim's bundle with all the same functionalities.

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or wherever you are used to put aliases and custom bash functions:

```
alias vim='/path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'
```